# How to delete all aux-files from terminal?

Tags: auxiliary-files

Is there a command to delete all auxiliary files within the terminal without compiling the `tex`-file first?

There is such an option for `latexmk` but then I have to build the `pdf` first.

*Edit*

Ok, I try to be more explicit: Sometimes things go wrong and one has to delete all the `aux`, `bbl`, `bcf` etc. files. Some editor have this option but since we can compile a `tex` file with the terminal I was wondering whether there is also a function/program which would delete all those created auxiliary files automatically; e.g. `$ cleartex .` for all auxiliary files in that directory.

As moewe suggests such a program could have the gitignore list as base to work with.

Comment: I assume you would have to have a list of extensions of temporary files and then go through it and delete files you find with the extensions listed there. A start could be https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/TeX.gitignore. I think I remember a different list with comments hosted on github, can't find it though.

Comment: erh, not understod, there are no aux files if the PDF has not been build. `latexmk -c *.tex` will remove all aux files generated from the given `.tex` files.

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean but `rm *.aux` removes all aux files from the  current directory (or `del` rather than `rm` in windows cmd prompt)

Comment: What would be the reason to delete the auxiliary files *before* running TeX? They are essential for the next run of TeX to be correct (or, at least, more correct than the previous one).

Comment: yes, they are essential, but I might start compiling from scratch and having all auxiliary files deleted before compiling (and then keep them for the next rounds compiling).

Comment: You could try parsing the `.log` file (with some scripting language) for the relevant filenames and delete those. That has the additional advantage that the files are deleted for a specific document (and not for other documents that might be present in the same folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, easiest method I can up with so far is

```
latexmk -C my-file.tex
```

I quote from the manual of `latexmk` for the flag `-C`:

> Clean up (remove) all regeneratable files generated by latex and
>   bibtex or biber. This is the same as the -c option with the addition
>   of dvi, postscript and pdf files, and those specified in the
>   $clean_full_ext configuration variable. This cleanup is instead of a
>   regular make ...

Comment: This command does not delete the bibtex aux files (.bib, .brf, .aux). Is there a way to do that too?

Comment: I hope you do not really want to delete your bibliography file. That is something you do need. For the others you still can run `rm *.{brf,aux}` in your command line.

Comment: That was a mistake, I meant .bbl instead of .bib.
I am aware of basic terminal commands, I just wanted to know if there was a latexmk or bibtex argument that would take care of that.

Comment: Yeah, somehow not all of the aux/log/etc-files are deleted by `latexmk -C`. I ended up using a makefile and have a command like `rm $(PROJECT)*.{blg,run.xml,toc,dep,fls,log,oai,bcf,bbl,aux,fdb_latexmk}` to get all or at least most of those files.